# Undo history cleared after removing comments - bug?

Tags: comment, history, undo

If I've written some code followed by a comment, like this:

```
x(*y*)
```

and I remove the comment by first removing the right delimiter and then the left, my undo history is cleared. Here are some conditions for this to occur:

- It doesn't matter whether I remove the `*` or the parentheses, or both
- Some code must precede the comment. Brackets, semicolons and commas don't seem to count.
- The comment cannot be empty.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to fix it?

I'm on 10.1, Student Edition.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What, precisely, is the issue?

Comment: It's right there in the title.

Comment: Can you post the output of `$Version`?

Comment: `"10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"`

Answer (score 5):

In an attempt to reproduce this issue, I began with

```
$Version
(* "10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)" *)
```

I then typed

```
x(*y*)
```

and deleted by hand the left asterisk, right asterisk, left parenthesis, and right parenthesis in turn.

```
xy
```

Next I began `Edit>Undo` until I reached

```
x (y*)
```

At that point, `Undo` was not grayed out, so the queue presumably was not empty.  Nonetheless, the final `Undo` was greeted by a beep, and the final asterisk was not restored.  Moreover, `Undo` became grayed out.  Selecting `Help>Why the Beep?` returned the message, `Cannot undo the last operation.`  So, I did not reproduce the issue given in the question, but I certainly obtained unexpected results.

On the other hand, when I deleted first the parentheses and then the asterisks in turn, I was able to restore all four characters using `Edit>Undo`.

Comment: By "second delimiter" I meant the right one. You have to remove either the right asterisk or parenthesis (or both), and then either the left asterisk or parenthesis (or both). I made some edits to OP to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If I use menu **Edit** > **Un/Comment Selection** (Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>) the operation can be reversed with the **Undo** command.  This is faster anyway and prevents broken syntax and syntax highlighting that occurs when you remove half a comment marker.

(I post this as an answer because I hope it is pragmatically just that.)